# Perl - How to get the number of elements in an anonymous array, for concisely trimming pathnames

Tags: perl, arrays, slice

I'm trying to get a block of code down to one line.  I need a way to get the number of items in a list.  My code currently looks like this:

```
# Include the lib directory several levels up from this directory
my @ary = split('/', $Bin);
my @ary = @ary[0 .. $#ary-4];
my $res = join '/',@ary;
lib->import($res.'/lib');
```

That's great but I'd like to make that one line, something like this:

```
lib->import( join('/', ((split('/', $Bin)) [0 .. $#ary-4]))  );
```

But of course the syntax `$#ary` is meaningless in the above line.

Is there equivalent way to get the number of elements in an anonymous list?

Thanks!

PS: The reason for consolidating this is that it will be in the header of a 
bunch of perl scripts that are ancillary to the main application, and I want this
little incantation to be more cut & paste proof.

**Thanks everyone**

There doesn't seem to be a shorthand for the number of elements in an anonymous
list.  That seems like an oversight.  However the suggested alternatives were all good.

I'm going with:

```
lib->import(join('/', splice( @{[split('/', $Bin)]}, 0, -4)).'/lib');
```

But Ether suggested the following, which is much more correct and portable:

```
my $lib = File::Spec->catfile(
                realpath(File::Spec->catfile($FindBin::Bin, ('..') x 4)),
               'lib');
lib->import($lib);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get a block of code down to one line? IF it's just to cut and paste, then that's your problem. Instead of that, make a library to do what you need to you don't have to cut and paste. That's why subroutines exist. :)

Comment: Can't put it in a lib, because this is the line of code that sets the include dir for the custom libs.  Also don't want to :)  But I think it's an interesting question on it's own anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lib->import(join('/', splice(@{[split('/', $bin)]}, 0, -4)).'/lib');
```

Comment: Edit, sorry for my stupid comment, I read your code wrong.  This is the answer.

Comment: This should work as-is, splice with three arguments is splice(array,offset,length) - the 0 specifies the beginning, the -4 means (array length-4).

Someone else mentioned that 0 .. -4 is legal. While true, you need to consider what that means to perl: 'count up from 0 to -4' (not very meaningful).

Answer (score 2):

Check the [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) function.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work.  `splice( split('/', $Bin), -4)` gives an error: Type of arg 1 to splice must be array (not split).  Splice seems to want an ACTUAL array.

Comment: A hack: you can use @{[split...]}. Effectively, it will create an array, take its reference and then dereference it. Also, note: you need both offset and length in splice: 0, -4.

Comment: @IK: Yes, including both the offset and length was my final problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate an array (such as removing the last n elements) with the [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) function, but you can also generate a slice of an array using a negative index (where -1 means the last element, -2 means the second to last, etc): e.g. `@list = @arr[0 .. -4]` is legal.

**However**, you seem to be going through a lot of backflips manipulating these lists when what you seem to be wanting is the location of a lib directory.  Would it not be easier to supply a -I argument to the perl executable, or use [$FindBin::Bin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) and [File::Spec->catfile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec) to locate a directory relative to the script's location?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd 'realpath';
use File::Spec;
use FindBin;

# get current bin
# go 4 dirs up,
# canonicalize it,
# add /lib to the end
# and then "use" it

my $lib = File::Spec->catfile(
                realpath(File::Spec->catfile($FindBin::Bin, ('..') x 4)),
               'lib');
lib->import($lib);
```

Comment: Thank you.  See other response on why splice doesn't work. I've tried negative indices on the slice like you show but get no output at all.  I'm already using FindBin::Bin to get the script dir, and File::Spec doesn't seem to do anything useful for me (would be nice if updir() took an argument so you could go up more than one directory.

Comment: @NXT: the "usual" way of going up directories in the filesystem is by using Cwd's `realpath` to canonicalize a path using `..`.

Comment: thanks, I get it now.  I didn't know that.  In this case I will take conciseness over correctness.  But I'm making a note of this for the future.